# IIS 6 application - override top level web.config

Tags: .net, iis-6, web-config

so, i have a main application that lies at www.mydomain.com
I've just created a sub-app that is going to reside at www.mydomain.com/subapp , but i want it to be completely independent from it's parent.
how can i force it to ignore it's parent's web.config?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't cleanly. There is no actual flag in IIS: it's contained in the web.config files themselves.

http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/how-to-disable-web-config-inheritance-for-child-applications-in-subfolders-in-asp-net.aspx

http://www.kowitz.net/archive/2007/05/16/stopping-asp.net-web.config-inheritance

Doesn't look straightforward, although I always thought it couldn't be done at all on IIS **6**.

Comment: ok, i figured, so how can i solve problems like:

"Could not load file or assembly 'HttpCompression' or one of its dependencies."
<add type="HttpCompression.HttpCompressionModule,HttpCompression" name="HttpCompression" />
?